# Know of any tools to monitor the REAL performance of an amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, monitoring

There are times (like this morning for 15 minutes) when the performance of my cc1.4xlarge is horrible and it is not anything running on my instance as evidenced by the aws console monitoring graphs and my own investigation.

It seems like the physical box that it is on is having problems or maybe Xen isn't properly allocating resources.

Are there any tools that will monitor not the "reported" stats on the CPU and disk, but do actual performance tests, e.g. divide some floats 1,000 times and make sure it completes within a typical time, write/read stuff to disk?

Comment: Don't know of any, but this is a good idea! To the float division that checks CPU performance I'd add some tests that for IO throughput - read and write large files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage Engine is an amazing Amazon EC2 Monitoring tool.
It has 30-days trial. You should try.

1. CPU Utilization, Network Traffic, Disk I/O
2. Metrics of Attached EBS Volumes
3. Out-of-the-box Performance Reports

> [Manage Engine WebSite](http://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/amazon-ec2-monitoring.html)

Comment: Looks like it would help with the EBS read and write latency, but it is too expensive for my tastes

Comment: Hi Chris. You didn't write anything about price :) So try this. Free. http://www.cacti.net/... This is the tutorial about amazon cloud monitoring with cacti. http://www.haughin.com/2009/04/15/monitor-your-servers-and-ec2-instances-with-cacti/,

Comment: It just says "Cloudproviderimage has stopped working" when I'm trying to connect :\

Answer (score 5):

CopperEgg monitors EC2 instances every 5 seconds and not only shows CPU and other key performance metrics, but CPU components, like Steal and IOwait, which can be real performance robbers on AWS.

http://copperegg.com/aws