# How to Monitoring performance Amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, instance

I want to monitor my large instance on amazon. CPU, disk etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Know of any tools to monitor the REAL performance of an amazon ec2 instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808797/know-of-any-tools-to-monitor-the-real-performance-of-an-amazon-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 6):

For a better monitoring system that is free, you should check out RevealCloud (http://www.copperegg.com/cloud).

Better than CloudWatch:

- free
- real-time (updates in seconds, not 1 or 5 minutes)
- shows more detail
- alerts
- easy install
- single dashboard view
- works on mobile devices

Comment: I just discovered copperegg and it's really cool! it is free for two servers and then you pay as you go. It's super easy to configure: only one command to run on your EC2 instance console, and your are setup! You can then easily share the stats with other people, setup alerts, etc.

Comment: Not free anymore... (2013-07-03)

Comment: link is 404 ! !

Answer (score 5):

Amazon provides CloudWatch for this out of the box when you launch an EC2 instance.  Just specify that you would like the instance monitored when starting it.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/

Comment: Although it's included with the EC2 service, the Cloudwatch web UI is pretty crappy. It's not realtime, doesn't auto-update, and you have to search for and manually select each metric you want to graph **EVERY** time you load the page. And for some reason it doesn't even use the tagged names of your instances (even though most other AWS services do), so you need to remember the serial numbers for your instances when searching...

Comment: @Cerin - While those may be valid points I don't think it warranted a downvote.  The question was how to monitor performance on EC2 and I provided the way that Amazon recommends.

Answer (score 1):

There is a freely available tool called the EC2 Health Monitor.

From its official description:

> ManageEngine supports the "Free EC2 Health Monitor Tool", allows you to monitor performance metrics like CPU Utilization, Network In, Network Out, Disk Read and Disk Write of AMI instances continuously. This tool presents the resource usage in an elegant graph and reports. It also shows the number of instances present and the number of instances that are in running state or stopped state in a tree view.
>
> ManageEngine EC2 Health Monitor Tool monitors the metrics of the AMI instances. You can monitor any number of instances using this tool. The best part is that this tool is made available to you absolutely FREE of cost.

To know more about tool please visit:

http://www.manageengine.com/free-ec2-health-monitor-tool/free-ec2-health-monitor-index.html

To download the ManageEngine Free EC2 Health Monitor Tool please visit:

http://www.manageengine.com/free-ec2-health-monitor-tool/download.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try Xervmon. They provide integrated cloud management with in depth monitoring on a single pane of glass.